# Edit the User Account for Pull Request that has been accepted

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

I was supposed to work on branch X0 of repository X using my user_x github account.

However, my github credentials in the cli were preconfigured as below

```
git config --global user.name user_a

git config --global user.email user_a@email.com
```

The pull request I created has been accepted which should not have happened. I found my mistake and I fixed my credentials locally. Now I want to edit the user info of the commit.  Is there way to edit the commit to replace author user_a with user_x?

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` are not authorization credentials. They're commit identification data. They're used during commit creation.

Comment: @phd, I understood what you are saying. I had commit info user_a setup in my cli but I configured ssh key of my terminal with user_x github account. the pull request I did, it went as user_a doing it. Is it possible to change user_a to user_x for this specific pull request?

Comment: How many commits are in the pull request? If there're many you need to rewrite many commits changing name/email. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+email+multiple+commits

Comment: @phd, just 1 commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320317/7976758 Fix `user.name`/`user.email` in the local config and rewrite one commit. `git rebase @~` is enough. To check it worked run `git show --format=fuller` and see author/commiter names/emails.